# Retain session when login in with Laravel Socialite in google or reset id with previous one

Tags: laravel

I currently have a Laravel app that signs in using Socialite.

```
public function redirectToGoogle(Request $request)
{
    return Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->redirect();
}
```

When it loads and redirects I lose the previous session id.
I need that session id because it's loaded in my db to track some cart info.
Is there away I can retain the previous session id when Socialite loads the google driver?

I can also reset the session id since I have it in my db.  However I don't know how to regenerate it with a custom string.

```
$request->session()->regenerate();
```

But passing it a custom string?

```
$request->session()->regenerate('some value');
session()->getId(); //does not regenerate 'some value'
```

Comment: try `$customId = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$request->session()->regenerate($customId);`

Comment: @NIKUNJKOTHIYA it regenerates but not the customId variable.  Only a random one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would setId like so:
session()->setId($myCustomId);
[From here](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Contracts/Session/Session.html)